# Variables are not saved in object

Tags: c#, xml, oop, mvvm

So I'm reading a file from XML and this works pretty well using the Debug-Output.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "Note")
    {
        Note n = new Note();

        reader.ReadToFollowing("NoteTitle");
        string s = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
        n.NoteTitle = s;
        Debug.WriteLine("s " + s);
        Debug.WriteLine("n " + n.NoteTitle);
     }
}
```

My problem is that

```
n.NoteTitle = s;
```

doesn't do anything so the second Debug prints only "n " and nothing else, while the first debug prints `"s Notetitle1"` correctly.

What is my problem?

Edit:
Sorry, implementation of NoteTitle:

```
private string _noteTitle = string.Empty;
    public string NoteTitle
    {
        get { return this._noteTitle; }
        set { RaisePropertyChanged("NoteTitle"); }
    }
```

Comment: And the implementation of Note.NoteTitle is what?

Comment: What is  your note class? More specific, what is NoteTile?

Comment: Yes, we really need the Node-class.

Comment: @CSharpened I don't think the XML is the problem here, the value is clearly being extracted (confirmed by the debug output). The issue is how the `Note` class has been implemented - more specifically the `NoteTitle` property.

Comment: Alexander I wonder if the problems is in this line `reader.ReadToFollowing("NoteTitle");` are you missing a `reader.ReadStartElement("Note");`for example which should be outside your while loop.. can you explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish when reading the XML File it seems that you are using a not so conventional way of reading XML

Comment: @James Yes I didnt spot that at first. Given that the XML tag content is displayed in the first debug then of course the second should work too. The only issue can be in the setter or getter but we do not have this to look at.

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ Linq2Xml isn't always the answer when parsing XML. XmlReader is *far* more efficient, regardless, parsing the XML isn't the problem here.

Comment: @James it's hard to give any good answer or advice when the OP won't show what the XML looks like wouldn't you agree..? also is reader defined as XMLReader..? one can not tell because that definition / implementation of the reader, the OP has not shown either..

Comment: @DJKRAZE no, the XML isn't the problem. The OP has pointed out that they are extracting the value from the XML, the trouble is getting property of `Note` to *retain* the value. Everyone is waiting for the OP to post the implementation of the `Note` class, or even just the implementation of the `NoteTitle` property. "*is reader defined as XmlReader?*" - from it's properties and methods it's pretty obvious i.e. `NodeType`/`ReadToFollowing` etc.

Comment: @James there's no performance issue with either of them..microsoft says this:`linq2xml` a complete **replacement** to the underlying xml api..

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ I never said there was a performance issue with them, I said "*XmlReader is far more efficient*", which it is. XmlReader allows you to *stream* the data from disk, LinqToSql will load the full document into memory first.

Comment: @James ahhh...nice catch..u r right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your implementation of the `NoteTitle` setter, you are forgetting to set the value of the private field i.e.

```
private string _noteTitle = string.Empty; 

public string NoteTitle 
{ 
    get { return this._noteTitle; } 
    set 
    { 
        this._noteTitle = value; // set the field value
        RaisePropertyChanged("NoteTitle"); 
    } 
}
```

This would explain why no value is being retained when you set the `NoteTitle` property.

Comment: i feel so stupid right now

Comment: @AlexanderCiesielski sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees :)

Answer (score 2):

The serialization in the OP seems to be throwing people off. I think the problem would be better expressed as:

```
    Note n = new Note();
    string s = "TEST";
    n.NoteTitle = s;
    Debug.WriteLine("s " + s);
    Debug.WriteLine("n " + n.NoteTitle);
```

The question becomes: Why does the second WriteLine() show "n " and not "n TEST"?

The answer is that there is something peculiar about the implementation of either the setter or the getter for Note.NoteTitle. For example, this implementation would have the effect:

```
public string NoteTitle
{
    get
    {
        return "";
    }

    set
    {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

Comment: `code` private string _noteTitle = string.Empty;
        public string NoteTitle
        {
            get { return this._noteTitle; }
            set { RaisePropertyChanged("NoteTitle"); }
        }